# Another option instead for MS Access Table

Tags: xml, ms-access, desktop-application, datastore

I have a desktop form application that currently uses and Microsoft Access MDB file to store the data.  If the users computer does not have access installed on their computer they have to download the MS Access Runtime to run the application or they get errors.

Is their a better option than using MDB files to store the data?  Should I use XML?

Thanks

Comment: How much data are you talking about? Does it need to get synchronized? What programming languages can you use?

Comment: It is not really an issue of what programing language can one use, but in fact what programing language and development system WAS used to create the application now? I don't really see why ms-access needs to be installed on the target system. Windows XP, Vista and windows 7 ALL shipped with the JET database engine and thus does NOT require you download and install the Access or the Access runtime to read and open those mdb files.  I suspect you are confusing the database part with the application part.  You need to clear up this issue.

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question. You should try to fix the error and then save yourself the time of revising the app for a new database engine.

Comment: What's the error message?   What are you using to access the database file?   ADO/DAO?  DAO/Jet 4.0 should work jsut fine as that's been included in the OS since Windows 2000.  If ADO then I'm not sure exactly what the answer would be.  If soemthing else then who knows.

Answer (score 2):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is widely considered to be a suitable alternative to MDB files.

Alternatively, you can use [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/express.aspx).

Comment: SQLite is zero footprint and does not need an install, I'm a fan +1 for simple single user apps.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

Google around there are many bindings for many languages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could use XML but this also puts data in the clear (anyone can open the xml file and look at the data). If you include a quiet install of mdac in your application installation, you can solve your problem of msaccess runtime error.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192009